# Callback function in helper

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, javascript

I have a callback function in my helper method but it does not execute.

Component:

```
save : function(component, event, helper) {
var fileInput = component.find("file").getElement(); 
var file = fileInput.files[0];  
var fr = new FileReader();

fr.onload = function() {
        var fileContents = fr.result;
        var base64Mark = 'base64,';
        var dataStart = fileContents.indexOf(base64Mark) + base64Mark.length;
        fileContents = fileContents.substring(dataStart);

        String fileNames = file.name;
        String fileTypes = file.type;
        String base64Datas = encodeURIComponent(fileContents),           
        helper.upload(component, event, helper, fileNames, fileTypes, base64Datas);
        alert("Return call");

    };
    fr.readAsDataURL(file);


}
```

Helper:

```
({
upload: function(component, event, helper, fileNames, fileTypes, base64Datas)
{   
    var actions = component.get("c.saveTheFile");
     actions.setParams({  
      //parentId: component.get("v.parentId"),  THIS IS NULL FOR SOME REASON
     fileName: fileNames,  
      base64Data: base64Datas, 
      contentType: fileTypes       //==== These params cause an error, not sure why
   });
    alert('check');
   actions.setCallBack(this, function(response){
       var state = response.getState();           
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            alert("From server: " + response.getReturnValue());
        }
        else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
            alert("INCOMPLETE");
        }
        else if (state === "ERROR") {
        alert("Error");
        }
       else{
           alert('other');
       }

   });
   alert('Did it work?');
   $A.enqueueAction(actions); 

 }
})
```

Apex/ServerSide

```
    @AuraEnabled
public static String saveTheFile(String fileName, String base64Data, String contentType) { 

    base64Data = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(base64Data, 'UTF-8');

    Attachment a = new Attachment();
    //a.parentId = parentId;   SINCE HELPER NULL, COMMENTED OUT

    a.Body = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64Data);
    a.Name = fileName;
    a.ContentType = contentType;

    insert a;

    return a.Name;
}
```

Not sure why when I add the extra parameters in the helper and apex class it causes an error:

> Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'apply' of
>   undefined]

And the callback function in the helper method doesn't execute. Not sure why.

Comment: Right off the bat you have commented out the closure of setParams `// });` and have a trailing common after the last parameter in that method `base64Data: base64Datas, `. Once you get the basic code structure fixed update your code and results

Comment: fixed comment issue and there is another argument after base64Data so that's why there is a comma there. I simplified the code on this website and must have missed the comment bit. Any thoughts as to why it doesn't work?

Comment: No idea. I don't even see any markup in what you put up as a component. What you have as a component looks like a helper or controller not a component. Have you done any debugging at all? I would assume that the onLoad function is not being executed

Comment: I feel like, but am not certain that the problem may lie in your `fr.onload`.  I wonder if you have access to component, event and helper( which you do not need to pass the helper method to your helper) objects when you pass it from the function.  I think it is a scope issue?  Someone can correct me if I'm wrong, but I would think the `= function()` type methods are not recommended in Lightning?

Comment: Would it be better just to delegate the onload to a helper method?

Comment: You can't attach a file without something to parent it to. If you're trying to save this as a related file, you need that parentId. Where is is supposed to be coming from? I don't see anything in your code that's passing it into your helper. Someplace it needs to be "set" for your helper to "get" it.